# Specify assembly for namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces, .net-assembly

Is there anyway to specify the assembly along with the namespace in C#?

For instance, if you reference both `PresentationFramework.Aero` and `PresentationFramework.Luna` in a project you might notice that both of them share the same controls in the same namespace but with different implementation.

Take `ButtonChrome` for example. It exists in both assemblies under the namespace `Microsoft.Windows.Themes`.

In XAML you include the assembly along with the namespace so here it's no problem

```
xmlns:aeroTheme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
xmlns:lunaTheme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Luna"

<aeroTheme:ButtonChrome ../>
<lunaTheme:ButtonChrome ../>
```

But in C# code behind I can't find anyway to create an instance of `ButtonChrome` in `PresentationFramework.Aero`.

The following code gives me **error CS0433** when compiling

```
using Microsoft.Windows.Themes;
// ...
ButtonChrome buttonChrome = new ButtonChrome();
```

> **error CS0433**: The type 'Microsoft.Windows.Themes.ButtonChrome' exists in both
>   'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\PresentationFramework.Aero.dll'
>   and
>   'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\PresentationFramework.Luna.dll'

Which is very understandable, the compiler has no way of knowing which `ButtonChrome` to choose because I haven't told it. Can I do that somehow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to specify an alias for the assembly reference and then import via the alias:

```
extern alias thealias;
```

See the properties window for the references.

Suppose you alias the aero assembly as "aero" and the luna assembly as "luna". You could then work with both types within the same file as follows:

```
extern alias aero;
extern alias luna;

using lunatheme=luna::Microsoft.Windows.Themes;
using aerotheme=aero::Microsoft.Windows.Themes;

...

var lunaButtonChrome = new lunatheme.ButtonChrome();
var aeroButtonChrome = new aerotheme.ButtonChrome();
```

See [extern alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Kent! For PresentationFramework.Aero I've set Aliases to aero and Embed Interop Types to False but I'm still getting `error CS0430: The extern alias 'aero' was not specified in a /reference option`. Anything else I need to do?

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug if the project contains ResourceDictionaries: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/615953/reference-aliases-are-ignored-on-projects-containing-some-xaml-files. I tried it out without any XAML files and it worked. This problem will be fixed in 4.5. Thanks again

Comment: @Meleak: interesting - I wasn't aware of that bug. Did you see the workaround? Is that an option for you?

Comment: I saw it but I didn't like the part about absolute paths. I tried it out anyway just for fun and it worked. But this wasn't my only option so I choose another path. Good thing to learn about aliases though, I'm guessing their only usage is this particular case :)

Answer (score 6):

Extern alias to the rescue, see documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx). Having added the assembly references and created the aliases Luna and Aero in the respective reference properties, here is some sample code you can try:

```
extern alias Aero;
extern alias Luna;

using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow: Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      var chrome1 = new Luna::Microsoft.Windows.Themes.ButtonChrome();
      var chrome2 = new Aero::Microsoft.Windows.Themes.ButtonChrome();
      MessageBox.Show(chrome1.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);
      MessageBox.Show(chrome2.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, thanks! I'm still missing something here, after setting aliases I'm still getting `error CS0430: The extern alias 'aero' was not specified in a /reference option`. Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: @Meleak: Select the assembly reference in the Solution Explorer window, head to the Properties window and change the value of the Aliases property from "global" to "Luna", "Aero" etc.

Comment: Thanks again. I did that but unfortunately there seems to be a bug. If the project contains ResourceDictionaries, aliases are ignored: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/615953/reference-aliases-are-ignored-on-projects-containing-some-xaml-files

Comment: @Meleak: Hm, thanks for the link, I didn't know about that bug. At least it gets fixed in 4.5, it seems.

Comment: Yeah, lets hope :) Without any XAML files it works great though. I accepted Kents answer because he was first but thanks for your help!

Comment: @Meleak: You're welcome. I actually typed the code into VS, so Kent got there faster (he actually edited his answer that was incorrect initially, otherwise I would've scrapped mine before posting), but no sweat, it's weekend time, and the point is we got to the bottom of it :)

Answer (score 1):

I have met a similar error regarding **System.NonSerializedAttribute** when referencing Microsoft.Scripting assembly, which also defines this attribute (clash found in Reference.cs file generated by service reference). The easiest way to solve this is very similar to defining aliases, but without the compilation headache:

In Visual Studio, go to the references of your project, select one of the assemblies generating the conflict, go to properties and fill Aliases value with something not equal to **global**.